# Pass client side value to server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to use a javascript variable value in server side.

Example:

**JavaScript**

```
var result =  false;
```

**CS Code**

```
if(result)
{
     Console.Write("Welcome..")
}
else
{
     Console.Write("plz try again..")
}
```

**Note**

I don't want to post a hidden field.

Comment: Hidden field is the best way to do it. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Thanks..My teacher told me that i cant use hidden field..:)

Comment: A hidden field may or may not be the best way to do it. The question has been abstracted to the point where it isn't possible to tell what the actual problem is. (It provides half a solution to an unspecified problem).

Comment: Teacher? That suggests this is homework and there is a good chance that the correct answer is "Whatever you were taught last week", which we can't possibly know.

Comment: I mean to say My office trainer(teacher)..I am in training period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With each request, any server side code will run and then any client side code will run. You can't switch between them at will.

Your options are:

1. Provide all the data to the client in the first place, then use JS to decide which of them to keep/delete/show/hide/etc
2. Use Ajax to make a second request to the server with the data you get from JS, return content, and then do something with that content in the JS callback function.
3. Make a second request to the server and load a complete new page.

Remember to [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/).

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Can you please tell me that how i can do this with Ajax. Do you have any link or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this use hidden fields...